# Defining __repr__(self) to be created dynamically in python

Tags: python, printing, instance-variables

I have a class

```
class FooBar(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        pass
```

and I want to implement the `__repr__` function. Since I am using FooBar as sort of a handy container and I add some attributes dynamically I thought of generating `__repr__` dynamically, too. (If this is bad praxis, please explain and enlighten me :-))

I thought of something like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<FooBar({WHAT IS ELEGANT AND GOES HERE?})>'.format(**self.__dict__)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Not specific enough information. Subjective. Your choice. What sort of stuff will it contain?

Comment: The question is: why are you using dynamic attributes? You can't use a dictionary for example? In you example, you can have a attribute for store the string `'<FooBar ...>'` and execute `self.yourstring.format` in __repr__, BUT, I think is better you avaliate other options.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> '<FooBar({!r})>'.format({'a':1, 'b':2})
"<FooBar({'a': 1, 'b': 2})>"
```

on Python2.6 you'd have to use `{0!r}`

I think

```
'<FooBar({!r})>'.format(vars(self))
```

is nicer than referring to `.__dict__`